# Nodes in the node editor are different than on tutorial

Tags: node-editor

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to use the Volumetric light, I have watched some tutorials and none serves me, this for example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67N7778WjLk

I use the version 2.72 b but when the boy tutorial, enter the node editor does not appear to me like I needed as indicated in the photo, someone can recommend me someone who can help me.

https://youtu.be/67N7778WjLk?t=3m36s

[image]

and me neither, not shown me the same components in the menu "add" in the node editor.

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Change Blender Render to Cycles. Top Right corner in your screen.

Comment: @LukeD oh man that really helped me, if you want to put an answer I would accept your answer

Comment: I have made an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Just to remove this question from unanswered list.*

To have the same settings as in provided tutorial change rander engine from *Blender Render* to *Cycles*.

[image]